# php 7 install throws "Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded" error

Tags: centos, php

I am using `salt` to provision my servers, and I just tried to upgrade to php 7 and although everything is installing correctly, anytime I run `php -v` or run any php anything it throw this at the head of any output: `Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded`.  If I uninstall if I see this, `Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Here is the full output from `php-v` with and with out the `php-opcache` installed.

#### With

```
Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
PHP 7.0.1 (cli) (built: Dec 16 2015 15:31:55) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

#### With out

```
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP 7.0.1 (cli) (built: Dec 16 2015 15:31:55) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

I install with this (in the salt state file)

```
remi-php70-repo:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - humanname: Remi PHP 7 Repository
    - baseurl: http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/php70/$basearch/
    - gpgcheck: 0
    - require_in:
      - pkg: php-fpm

php-fpm:
  pkg.latest:
    - pkgs:
      - php-fpm

php-opcache:
  pkg.latest:
    - pkgs:
      - php-opcache
```

And I know it is installing from the 7.0 repo based on a `yum install php-opcache` and then a `php -v`

#### terminal output

```
[root@mage2appblock vagrant]# yum install php-opcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                    |  14 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.spro.net
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
 * updates: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
base                                                                                             | 3.7 kB     00:00
centos-plus-repo                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00
epel                                                                                             | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                               35% [============-                      ]  0.0 B/s | 2.1 MB     --:-- ETA epel/primary_db                                                                                  | 5.7 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00
mysql56-community-repo                                                                           | 2.5 kB     00:00
remi-php70-repo                                                                                  | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-rep                                                                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-rep/primary_db                            7% [==                                 ]  0.0 B/s |  97 kB     --:-- ETA remi-rep/primary_db                           37% [=============                      ] 655 kB/s | 510 kB     00:01 ETA remi-rep/primary_db                                                                              | 1.3 MB     00:00
repo-saltstack-el6                                                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                          | 3.4 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-opcache.x86_64 0:7.0.1-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                    Arch                  Version                          Repository                      Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-opcache                x86_64                7.0.1-1.el6.remi                 remi-php70-repo                135 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 135 k
Installed size: 378 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       18% [======-                            ]  0.0 B/s |  25 kB     --:-- ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       31% [===========                        ]  27 kB/s |  43 kB     00:03 ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       38% [=============-                     ]  28 kB/s |  52 kB     00:02 ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       48% [================-                  ]  29 kB/s |  65 kB     00:02 ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       55% [===================-               ]  29 kB/s |  75 kB     00:02 ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       69% [========================           ]  31 kB/s |  94 kB     00:01 ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm       90% [===============================-   ]  35 kB/s | 122 kB     00:00 ETA php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm                                                          | 135 kB     00:02
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64                                                                  1/1
  Verifying  : php-opcache-7.0.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64                                                                  1/1

Installed:
  php-opcache.x86_64 0:7.0.1-1.el6.remi

Complete!
[root@mage2appblock vagrant]# php -v
Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
PHP 7.0.1 (cli) (built: Dec 16 2015 15:31:55) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

I have not be able to find anything related on this at all.  Any ideas would be great.

Notes that may be helpful:

1. This is a `vagrant` server loading CentOS 6.5
2. Provisioning is provided via `salt`
3. the install is clean when `salt` runs

### Updates

So I have tried with out installing the Zen Opcache thinking it was complied in with php 7, it is not.  I am trying to look at what is loading or if there is some issue with the opcache.ini file I provision in.  Maybe there is some new settings with the php5 moving to php 7 in that area.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out that I was loading a `opcache.ini` file which was what php 5 used by default, but in php 7 it was loaded as `10-opcache.ini` by default so when my file of opcache.ini was provisioned in it had two `.ini` files and was trying to load the plugin twice.

I'm not going to delete this question as I believe it is an error that is easy to overlook and may be helpful since you can't really google that error phase and not one place that had anything on it said anything about doubled ini files or declaring the extension twice.

Comment: Happend to me as well today after I upgraded to:  php7.0-cli 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-common 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-fpm 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-gd 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-json 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-mysql 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-opcache 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
 php7.0-readline 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: Same thing, happened to me as well today with PHP7. I ran `ls -la /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d` and sure enough, there were two opcache symlinks in there: `10-opcache.ini` and `20-opcache.ini`. Out of the two `20-opcache.ini` had the older timestamp, so I erased that symlink (`sudo rm /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-opcache.ini`), and all is well now. Thanks!

Comment: So it turns out it was a bug in php 7.0.3.1 and is fixed by 7.0.3.2 see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0/7.0.3-2

Comment: I confirm it's fixed now

Comment: That was useful. In my case, I don't know why, I had on php7.0, both 05-opcache.ini and 10-opcache.ini. I removed the second and the warning disapeared. I'll comment back here, if it breaks something. Using PHP 7.0.15 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Same here. But our issue was 05-opcache.ini and 10-opcache.ini files existing. This randomly started happening after a maintenance window in aws. Box's config didn't change by us. Weird.

Comment: I found `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/opcache.ini` as well, I deleted it and the error was gone